# Access Graphing with inconsistent x values

Tags: excel, ms-access, graph, charts

I need to make a graph from a list of values that don't line up with each other.  There are samples being taken in a process at certain times, but they aren't always the same.  For Sample A, the times are 1pm, 3pm, 5pm, etc.  For Sample B the times are 2pm, 4pm, 6pm, etc.  For Sample C the times are 1:30pm, 3:30pm, 5:30pm etc.

If I graph each sample individually they are fine, but when you graph them together you can only get the xy scatter points, but no lines since it thinks there are missing values.  I just need a rough comparison of increase/decrease over time.  If I could connect the dots with lines ignoring the missing values that would be great!  I just don't know how to do that...  Any suggestions?

This is for Access, otherwise this would work.
[Excel - Connect Data Points with Line](https://superuser.com/questions/246614/excel-making-line-charts-so-the-line-goes-through-all-data-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use old excel knowledge.  In Access, set up the graph with xy scatter like you want.  Then Tools > Options > Chart and select Interpolated.  That should do it!  Just took a while to find what it might be called and where it might be located.